# Does Qt have an equivalent to .NET's NotImplementedException or define for that?

Tags: c++, qt, exception

Does Qt(C++) contain an exception equivalent to .NET's NotImplementedException?

Qt framework has a plenty defines for a lot of things(like Q_UNUSED), so maybe they got the same for not implemented methods.

I already had a look at this question [Does C++ have an equivalent to .Net's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24469927/does-c-have-an-equivalent-to-nets-notimplementedexception), but want to clarify this question for Qt specifically (neither want to create additional hierarchy for exceptions).

Comment: Not AFAIK, but you could build your own based on `QException`

Comment: Except Concurrency module which helps with massive parallelization none of Qt throws exceptions (yet you can).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Qt does not use exceptions outside of the concurrency framework.

You want to use C++'s standard exceptions for that.