# NotImplementedException C++

Tags: c++, move

From the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24469927/does-c-have-an-equivalent-to-nets-notimplementedexception) I implemented my class `NotImplementedException`

```
//exceptions.h
namespace base
{
    class NotImplementedException : public std::logic_error
    {
    public:
        virtual char const* what() { return "Function not yet implemented."; }
    };
}
```

In another class I would like to throw the following exception (same namespace):

```
    std::string to_string() override
    {
        throw NotImplementedException();
    }
```

The `to_string` method is an overriden method from an abstract base class.

```
namespace BSE {
    class BaseObject
    {
        virtual std::string to_string() = 0;
    };
}
```

Unfortunately, the compilation of the previous code shows me this error:

```
error C2280: BSE::NotImplementedException::NotImplementedException(void)': attempting to reference a deleted function`
```

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31264984/c-compiler-error-c2280-attempting-to-reference-a-deleted-function-in-visual) I understood that the problem it has something to do with move constructor or assignment which according to [cppreference.com - throw (1)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/throw) this could be the case:

> First, copy-initializes the exception object from expression (this may call the move constructor for rvalue expression, and the copy/move may be subject to copy elision)

I tried adding

```
    NotImplementedException(const NotImplementedException&) = default;
    NotImplementedException& operator=(const NotImplementedException&) = default;
```

to my class but that gives me

```
error C2512: 'BSE::NotImplementedException': no appropriate default constructor available
```

and as far as I know `std::logic_error` has no default constructor defined.

**Q**:How do I get around this?

Comment: 1. `std::logic_error` has explicit constructors. You should call one of them.

Comment: 2. Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10948316/throw-new-stdexception-vs-throw-stdexception

Comment: Ah, actually the `new` snuck in there because I was playing around - that wasn't intentional. And does this mean that the implementation I found is wrong? Or are there different circumstances I'm not aware of?

Comment: You may want to correct the typo in the title to get better searchs

Comment: Should this exception derive from `logic_error`? I don't think it's a logic error...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should be something like:

```
namespace base
{
    class NotImplementedException : public std::logic_error
    {
    public:
        NotImplementedException () : std::logic_error{"Function not yet implemented."} {}
    };
}
```

And then

```
std::string to_string() override
{
    throw NotImplementedException();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Exception which doesn't say what is not implemented is quite annoying, so I would do this like this:

```cpp
namespace base
{
    class NotImplementedException : public std::logic_error
    {
    public:
        using logic_error::logic_error;
         
        NotImplementedException(
                const std::source_location location = std::source_location::current())
            : logic_error{std::format("{} is not implemented!", location.function_name())}  
       {}
    };
}
```

Then

```cpp
std::string to_string() override
{
    throw NotImplementedException("to_string for object");
    // or using source_location:
    throw NotImplementedException();
}
```

C++20 features are cool for this case, but not obligatory (and still not available on most compilers).

Some [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Y6GGEq1Ma).